# Netbeans build fail from time to time

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

I am a NetBeans user since 2009, but now I'm facing some problems that I can't explain. My project has dependencies on some other projects, and they have dependencies on some other projects (it's a big thing) and when Cleaning and Building, sometimes I have this result:

http://pastebin.com/gigXVLsc

I have nothing opened that could block this deletion. Also, if I click to Clean and Build again (just after this fail) I manage to do the operation.

http://pastebin.com/mzuvqM0R

I don't know what's causing this, maybe I should delete everything and link all the projects again?

I'm under Windows 8 64 bits using Netbeans 7.2

Comment: We've had this problem for some time at our work place for a while. It appears that NetBeans background scanning (or some other Netbeans process) is maintains a reference to the files. I've been trialling a setting which seems to be helping. When I get to work, I will post it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've been having this issue with NetBeans since the late version of 6 and above.

After much hunting and reading, I added `-J-Dorg.netbeans.modules.masterfs.watcher.disable=true` to the `netbeans_default_options` of the `etc/netbeans.cfg` in the NetBeans installation folder.

While this has not ridden me of the issue entirely, it has significantly reduced the issue.

- Goto you're Netbeans installation location, open the `netbeans.cfg` in you the `etc` folder.
- Find the `netbeans_default_options` (make a copy of the exitsting option and add a `#` to the start of the line to comment it out`
- Add `-J-Dorg.netbeans.modules.masterfs.watcher.disable=true` to the end of the line (making sure it's within in the quotes)
- Restart NetBeans...

Hope this helps reduce the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, haven't face this issue again since I did it. Do you know what is the downside of disabling this watcher?

Comment: I can only imagine that it will take longer to update its internal cache...but it was never that fast for me anyway

Answer (score 0):

Seems while cleaning your server is running and that is not allowing you to delete certain .jar file, or somehow those jar files are occupied

Comment: The application is not running while trying to Clean and Build, and there is no other software open besides Netbeans. If I try to redo the operation just after it fails, the operation is a success.